# How to split a string into two sub-stings using a string matching in a data frame

Tags: python, string, split

I have a dataframe with the sentences column and a column with a word present in the sentences.I want to string match the word to the word in the sentences column and create a data frame by splitting the sentences into two different sentences and placing them into separate columns as mentioned below.

I have df1

| Sentence | word |
| --- | --- |
| me and John went to the area within 20 minutes | went to |
| I ran out of the house and jumped to a conclusion | jumped |

I want to create df2 as below.

| Sentence | word | source | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| me and John went to the area within 20 minutes | went to | me and John | the area within 20 minutes |
| I ran out of the house and jumped to a conclusion | jumped | I ran out of the house and | to a conclusion |

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to post your coding attempt to solve this, and to ask a *specific* question. What have you tried, what is the issue?  (Please update the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `str.split` method you can specify what to split on there:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({"sentences":["me and John went to the area within 20 minutes","I ran out of the house and jumped to a conclusion"], 
"words":["went to","jumped"]})


source,target = zip(*[(s.split(t)[0],s.split(t)[-1]) for s,t in zip(data["sentences"],data["words"])])
data["source"] = source
data["target"] = target
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could use regex and create your new dataframe:

```
df2 = {"Sentence":[], "word":[], "source":[] ,"target":[]}

for d in df.iterrows() :
    source,_ ,target = re.findall(f'(.*) ({d[1].word})(.*)', d[1].Sentence)[0]
    df2['Sentence'].append(d[1].Sentence)
    df2['word'].append(d[1].word)
    df2['source'].append(source)
    df2['target'].append(target)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

output:
[image]